# Can indexing be a solution to SQL deadlocks that are caused due to lock resources?

Tags: sql-server, deadlock, sql-server-2019

This question pertains purely to deadlock caused due to lock resources.

I am reading this article: [Using a Clustered Index to Solve a SQL Server Deadlock Issue](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2517/using-a-clustered-index-to-solve-a-sql-server-deadlock-issue/)

They have explained how adding nonclustered index, or clustered index solves the deadlock problem.

The general idea is that - the UPDATE query will not block because of the index seek that will result in only few rows being locked.

However, the way SQL server works is - the engine at any point (for example after 5000 row level locks [Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EqfAPZGKifA at 30:25]) decide to elevate the lock to page or table level lock, thus locking the entire object (table for example). So is the solution given in this article - that adding clustered index is a solution to deadlocks - reliable?

Comment: Indexes can help reduce the number of deadlocks but bear in mind that the transaction isolation level will also dictate the number of deadlocks that you get. The options read committed snapshot isolation and snapshot isolation can reduce further the number of deadlocks by using row versioning with previous versions being stored temporarily in TempDB. You should write retry logic in your code and can use the option deadlock priority to determine which transaction is chosen as the deadlock victim if needed. See https://www.sqlshack.com/snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server/

Comment: Comments should only be used for asking for clarification, or to leave constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the post, or to add relevant but minor or transient information to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the question has been updated), or to provide site usage guidance.  See the [help](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) for details.

Answer (score 6):

At the root of it all, deadlocks are fundamentally a performance problem. After all, regardless of the order of the code and all the other common deadlock causes, if all the transactions complete before any other transaction can start, you won't see a deadlock.

Fundamentally, you're still best off by fixing the root causes causing the deadlock (usually, but not always, accessing tables in different orders in different transactions), but simply doing performance tuning fixes a lot of deadlocks. With that in mind, yeah, the right index could absolutely mitigate the number of deadlocks you experience.

Although, as with anything else, it does depend on your code, the extent of the problem, the indexes chosen, load, changes over time, statistics, all the things that can affect performance.

Comment: `Deadlocks are fundamentally a performance problem` - do you mean this is a database performance problem? I was thinking that it is more of problem with way application (that uses the database) logic is designed.

Comment: Yeah, databases. The root cause of the deadlock is usually application logic, yes. That's where the real problem is. However, you'll never see it if everything goes really fast. It's all about the locks being held by transactions. Get them out of the way faster, reduced, or even eliminated, chances for collisions. As I said above, I'd still focus on the code, but making it run faster will absolutely help.

Comment: By faster you mean the system RAM? Or indexes? Because as shown in the youtube video, even if index is added, and thus it makes the query perform fast, the engine might still choose to lock entire table or page anyways (if more than a certain number of rows need updating). So indexing may not be the solution at all.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I was careful to put in caveats in the statement above, "...you're still best off by fixing the root causes...". I didn't say it was a magic bullet. Just that it can help.

Comment: @variable: No they're not. I got a deadlock from updating two rows that happened to be adjacent to each other because SQL server couldn't handle it whereas in turn these updates had to be in two different transactions because SQL server couldn't handle a different thing elsewhere. But the actual lock diagram showed no possible deadlock.

Comment: If the diagram didn't show deadlock then how do you know that there was a deadlock? Note that the query shown in diagram doesn't always mean that it caused the deadlock. It could well be a query prior to it (but in the same process) that owns the lock which resulted in the deadlock. I think the deadlock chain is usefull in such situations to point which query held the lock.

Comment: @joshua There had to be a deadlock or you wouldn't get a deadlock error or a deadlock graph. As variable says, the query could be elsewhere. Also, "adjacent to each other" rows certainly implies they are on the same page, so a page lock could lead to a deadlock.

Comment: @GrantFritchey: It turns out that SQL server implements predicate locks by locking the previous and next rows on some index used to resolve the where clause. This is not correct and causes deadlocks that do not appear on the hand drawn lock graph.

Comment: "deadlocks are fundamentally a performance problem" Strongly disagree here, if your application depends on execution time in order to not crash your application has a bug and you're relying on luck for it to work, it's a matter of time until it doesn't and then you may be in for really bad consequences. Deadlocks are caused by bad application logic.

Comment: Well, I didn't say you should rely on luck. In fact, I said, fixing the underlying problem is the right way to go. But, it's more than OK to disagree.

Answer (score 3):

To rephrase Tolstoy
"All happy databases are alike, each unhappy database is unhappy in its own way".
(stolen from someone but can't remember to give the credit - sorry).
By which I mean there are many sorts of deadlock and each will require their own solution, but certainly adding an index is one of the more common remedies.
Note that you can only get deadlocks with exclusive locks & it ought to be pretty rare in an OLTP system to be modifying over 5000 rows.

Comment: I have updated question to convey that I am referring to deadlocks caused due to lock resources. It maybe rare for OLTP system to be modifying over 5000 rows. So are you saying that for few rows this is a fine solution and for 5000+ rows this is not a solution?

Comment: a classic example of when an index will fix a deadlock is if there is no supporting index then the query will scan the table & as Grant says this will make the transaction take a long time, therefore more chance that another session will request conflicting locks. If you add an index so that the query is fast it REDUCES the chance of a deadlock, note that you can't always eliminate deadlocks so it is important that the application code can detect and retry the transaction if a deadlock is encountered.

Comment: As shown in the youtube video, even if index is added, and thus it makes the query fast, the engine might still choose to lock entire table or page anyways (if more than a certain number of rows need updating). So indexing may not be the solution at all.

Comment: Nope. Not always. The single best solution is to fix the underlying code. However, indexing can absolutely help. Yes, given the right index, etc., all the caveats.

Comment: Deadlocks can happen between readers and writers: [Lookups, Deadlocks, and You](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sql-server/lookups-deadlocks-and-you/)